# chrome extension, webpage screenshot, especially with flash video playing

Tags: flash, video, google-chrome-extension, screenshot

I am trying to develop a chrome extensions, which takes screenshot of the entire page, especially with a flash video playing. Just like extensions webpage screenshot(http://www.webpagescreenshot.info/). This plugin is real good, but I don't know how it work.
  I have search mush about screenshot of chrome extensions, but they do not work with flash video playing.
  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpage Screenshot extension it's awesome.
It is uses chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab method:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab

You are right that in the past, this API doesn't work with flash, but today, it is capture flash!